# Disabling months in bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am trying to disable months in a datepicker using the option datesDisabled. According to the docs it should work by passing an array of strings in the format of what I'm using for the datepicker but I can't get it to work.

HTML:

```
<div class="modal-body">
 <div class="input-append date" id="datepicker1" data-date="Aug-2015" data-date-format="mm-yyyy" data-dates-disabled="Sep-2015,Oct-2015" style="display:inline-block; font-weight:bold;">
  Check In: <input  type="text" readonly="readonly" name="date1" >
  <span class="add-on"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>      
 </div>       
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var dateStart = new Date();
dateStart.setDate(dateStart.getDate()-1);

$( document ).ready(function() {
    var dp = document.getElementById("datepicker1");

    $("#datepicker1").datepicker( {
        format: "mm-yyyy",
        startView: "months", 
        minViewMode: "months",
        startDate: dateStart,
        datesDisabled: dp.dataset.datesDisabled.split()
    }).datepicker("setDate",null);

});
```

**Update:**

It doesn't look like this will get answered so I decided to try and do this by finding all of the months and changing them to the disabled class. The problem is that I can't detect the clicks to be able to get the year of the current calendar.

HTML of the datepicker header:

```
  <tr>
   <th style="visibility: hidden;" class="prev">«</th>
   <th colspan="5" class="datepicker-switch">2015</th>
   <th style="visibility: visible;" class="next">»</th>
  </tr>
```

Javascript:

```
$("th.next:first").click(function(){
    var currentYear = $("th.datepicker-switch:first").html();
    console.log("current year is " + currentYear); // nothing happens here
});
```

What's the correct way to detect clicks on elements inside of the datepicker?

Comment: works for me http://jsfiddle.net/z2v31Leo/

Comment: I checked your Fiddle and Sep 2015 and Oct 2015 are still enabled?

Comment: oh. i didn't check that. will update the fiddle in some time. a little busy now

Comment: ok so i've been trying to work on the fix for your issue but m having a hard time. i see that you've updated your question and you're looking for a way to detect click events inside the datepicker. you can use the `changeDate` event. try this `.on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        console.log(ev);
    });`

Comment: Updated @Sushil fidlde --> https://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/z2v31Leo/2/

Comment: @JSantosh your fiddle is throwing an error and what have you changed in the fiddle? its the same as mine

Comment: I changed the one line to this `datesDisabled: dp1.getAttribute("data-dates-disabled").split()` because IE doesn't support datasets. Isn't `changeDate` fired when the user selects a date? I need to detect paging back and forth threw different year views.

Comment: @Sushil . i just added ` endDate:dateStart,` and  fiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/z2v31Leo/2/.    actually the js files are loaded with `http`, but if you click above fiddle it is opening `https`.

Comment: `http` and `https` have got nothing to do with your fiddle throwing error before. my fiddle works with `http` and you can use `http` in fiddles as well. your new fiddle works fine. you can post it as an answer if that is what @user1601513 wants.

Comment: @JSantosh - your Fiddle just limits available months to the current month. I can't even get into the next year????

Comment: thats because he's setting `endDate` as `startDate` so you wont be able to select any other dates.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the datepicker's `show` event to disable unavailable months:

```
var datesToDisable = $('#datepicker1').data("datesDisabled").split(',');
  // or...
  // var datesToDisable = ["Sep-2015", "Oct-2015"];

//var dateStart = new Date();
//dateStart.setDate(dateStart.getDate()-1);

$('#datepicker1').datepicker({
        format: "mm-yyyy",
        startView: "months", 
        minViewMode: "months",
        //startDate: dateStart
        //datesDisabled: dp.dataset.datesDisabled.split()
    }).on("show", function(event) {

  var year = $("th.datepicker-switch").eq(1).text();  // there are 3 matches

  $(".month").each(function(index, element) {
    var el = $(element);

    var hideMonth = $.grep( datesToDisable, function( n, i ) {
                  return n.substr(4, 4) == year && n.substr(0, 3) == el.text();
                });

    if (hideMonth.length)
      el.addClass('disabled');

/* To hide those months completely...
    if (hideMonth.length)
      el.hide();
*/
  });
});
```

Here's an example: https://jsfiddle.net/zadaey92/1/

Answer (score 1):

Had similar issue to disable months and found shorter solution with `beforeShowMonth` option:

```
var monthsToDisable = ['2019-09'];
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm",
    startView: "months", 
    minViewMode: "months",
    beforeShowMonth: function(date) {
        var formattedDate = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM');
        return $.inArray(formattedDate, monthsToDisable) < 0;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the datepicker plugin `datesDisabled` takes only dates, NOT MONTHS. check the below code

`if (this.o.datesDisabled.length > 0 &&
                $.grep(this.o.datesDisabled, function(d){
                    return isUTCEquals(date, d); }).length > 0) {
                cls.push('disabled', 'disabled-date');
            }`

so if you pass a month in format `sep-2015` the function `isUTCEquals` returns false. So the Months will not be disabled.
above code is present in the below JS.

latest version JS  -> http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js

**To detect clicks inside datepicker**

there are some events in this plugins -->http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/stable/events.html#events

for example :`changeMonth`  event.

`$("#datepicker1").on('changeMonth',function(date){
console.log(date.date.getMonth()+1);
})
});`

updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/santoshj/z2v31Leo/3/

Comment: J Santosh - I tried the few events that are available and they wont work for me. I don't even care if someone clicks a month because I only want to show months that are available for rent. The only thing that I need to get through is reading the year when `next` or `prev` are clicked.