# how to Display specific months in boostrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I use date picker with only option with months but i need to display some months for this date picker like (May ,Nov)

**I use Following code**:

```
$('.month-year').datepicker({
      format: "mm-yyyy",
      viewMode: "months", 
      minViewMode: "months"
})
```

**Current Output**
[image]

*From Above Display only months (May ,Nov).

Comment: So, you want to disable Feb to Nov months?

Comment: Display Months only May And Nov.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure if you want to just make the other months inactive or to hide them completely from the date picker, so I've included both options.  The demo currently hides them completely.

```
var monthsToShow = ['May', 'Nov'];

$('#example1').datepicker({
  format: "MM yyyy",
  minViewMode: 1,
  autoclose: true
}).on("show", function(event) {
  $(".month").each(function(index, element) {

    var el = $(element);

    // to make other months inactive use this:
    if ($.inArray(el.text(), monthsToShow) >= 0)
      el.removeClass('disabled');
    else
      el.addClass('disabled');

    // to hide inactive months use this:
    if ($.inArray(el.text(), monthsToShow) >= 0)
      el.show();
    else
      el.hide();    
  });
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/awv3cx4x/

Comment: This solution does not account for years, isn't it?
Meaning, cannot set different months disabled per selected year.

Answer (score 0):

you can use beforeShowDay event listener

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
  beforeShowDay: disableSpecificWeekDays
});

var monthsToDisable = [1, 2, 3];

function disableSpecificWeekDays(date) {
    var month = date.getMonth();
    if ($.inArray(month, monthsToDisable) != -1) {
        return [false];
    }
    return [true];
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Fa8Xx/4333/)

Comment: OP is looking for Bootstrap Datepicker and not jQuery Datepicker

Comment: @Newbee Dev:  Code  Not Working. i Use Bootstrap Datepicker

Answer (score 0):

try this answer from @J Santosh

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32103637/6952155

this is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/santoshj/z2v31Leo/3/

snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    var dateStart = new Date();
dateStart.setDate(dateStart.getDate()-1);
    var dp = document.getElementById("datepicker1");

    $("#datepicker1").datepicker( {
        format: "mm-yyyy",
        startView: "months", 
        minViewMode: "months",
        startDate: dateStart,       
        datesDisabled: dp.dataset.datesDisabled.split()
    }).datepicker("setDate",null);
$("#datepicker1").on('changeMonth',function(date){
console.log(date.date.getMonth()+1);
})
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.4/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-body">
 <div class="input-append date" id="datepicker1" data-date="Aug-2015" data-date-format="mm-yyyy" data-dates-disabled="Sep-2015,Oct-2015" style="display:inline-block; font-weight:bold;">
  Check In: <input  type="text" readonly="readonly" name="date1" >
  <span class="add-on"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>      
 </div>       
</div>
```

Comment: I Need To Display Only May and Nov Months.

Comment: you can edit that code. i already give you the working code that disables the months why not play with it? your expecting for an answer that give you the exact output you want? effort man.