# Set disabled months in bootstrap datepicker using array of date strings is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a datepicker which has the following configuration:

HTML:

```
<div class="input-group date">
  <input type="text" id="datepick" class="form-control"/>
  <span class="input-group-addon">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
  </span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var datesToDisable = ["2016-11-01","2016-08-01","2016-06-01",
                      "2016-05-01","2016-04-01","2015-12-01","2015-09-01"];

$('#datepick').datepicker({
  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  minViewMode: 1, // 1 for months
  maxViewMode: 2, // 2 for years
  startDate: '-36m',
  endDate: '+0m',
  autoclose: true,
  toggleActive: true
});

$('#datepick').datepicker('setDatesDisabled', datesToDisable);
```

Then later an async call retrieves an array of dates (here represented by the `datesToDisable` variable) which are passed to the datepicker using the `setDatesDisabled` method (as indicated on the last line of the code snippet), but it is not working, as the months for the passed dates are still selectable within the calendar.

Questions: Is this the correct way to set disabled months in the bootstrap datepicker calendar? Will I need to pass all dates within a month to disable a particular month?

You can check it in the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/javlc/52g9xcz2/

Comment: Closely related (and it seems it cannot be done): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32082524/disabling-months-in-bootstrap-datepicker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the datepicker's `.on("show")` function to alter the display. I've used jQuery's `grep` to find matches with your `datesToDisable` array. If there are any matches then I apply the `disabled` class to that element.

```
var datesToDisable = ["2016-11-01","2016-08-01","2016-06-01",
                      "2016-05-01","2016-04-01","2015-12-01","2015-09-01"];

var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 
              'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

$('#example1').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    minViewMode: 1, // 1 for months
    maxViewMode: 2, // 2 for years
    startDate: '-36m',
    endDate: '+0m',
    autoclose: true,
    toggleActive: true}).on("show", function(event) {

  var year = $("th.datepicker-switch").eq(1).text();  // there are 3 matches

  $(".month").each(function(index, element) {

    var el = $(element);

    var hideMonth = $.grep( datesToDisable, function( n, i ) {
                  return n.substr(0, 4) == year && months[parseInt(n.substr(5, 2)) - 1] == el.text();
                });

    if (hideMonth.length)
      el.addClass('disabled');

    /* To hide them...
    if (hideMonth.length)
      el.hide();
    */
  });
});
```

JsFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/k144qmct/1/

Comment: Yes, practically this solves the situation. Excellent!

Comment: The [documentation](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#datesdisabled) is inaccurate: "Array of date strings or a single date string formatted in the given date format".

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap `setDatesDisabled` accepts only `dates` and not `months`. One solution that I'm develop is the following:

First of all, we have to create a new array: `var dates=[]`.

For every item from `datesToDisable` array, we need to `push` into `dates` all the dates from item `month`.

```
var datesToDisable = ["2016-11-01","2016-08-01","2016-06-01",
                  "2016-05-01","2016-04-01","2015-12-01","2015-09-01"];
```

For instance, we have `2016-11-01`. You have to add all `days` from `November(11)` month.

For this, I used `daysInMonth` method in order to find out the number of the days for a month.

```
function daysInMonth(month,year) {
    return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
}

daysInMonth(2016,11,0) //30
```

And the last step is to `pass` **dates** array to `datesDisabled` property.

Here is [**working solution**](https://jsfiddle.net/f50ga49j/8/).

Comment: Not sure you noticed, but your solution is not working, 
The dates (i.e. for Nov 2016) keep enabled, but also, I am looking to have the datepicker calendar disabled *at the month level*, not the date level.

Comment: I see what you mean, it is working on the wrong month (that can be tweaked), but I am looking for a solution that will disable the actual month, *when using the month view (not the date view)*.